# line 596, in call_cpp_shape_fn raise ValueError(err.message) ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, kaggle

I am trying to learn Keras by example and found this code on Kaggle. How can I make this work for Keras with TensorFlow backend?

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/kaggle_distracted_driver$ python run_keras_simple.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Read train images
Load folder c0
Load folder c1
Load folder c2
Load folder c3
Load folder c4
Load folder c5
Load folder c6
Load folder c7
Load folder c8
Load folder c9
Directory doesnt exists
('Train shape:', (0, 1, 96, 128))
(0, 'train samples')
('Split train: ', 0)
('Split valid: ', 0)
('Split holdout: ', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_keras_simple.py", line 189, in <module>
    input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 294, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 398, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 569, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 632, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 164, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 442, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2206, in conv2d
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, kernel, strides, padding=padding)
  File "/home/mona/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 394, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/home/mona/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mona/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2390, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/mona/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1785, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/mona/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 596, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)
```

This input shape is in theano format, in Tensorflow the channels dimension goes at the end. You need to change the input shape to:

```
input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

And also make sure that the input data (train and validation) are in the same format, with the channels dimension at the end of the shape tuple.

Comment: please have a look at this, after I fixed that one, I got this error: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5145

Comment: @MonaJalal Seems you didn't reshape the input data to have compatible dimensions as said by my last paragraph.